# The SAC will become unavailable soon

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I tried to install .net framewrok 4.7.2 in windows server 2012. After the installation was completed, the server restarted. But, it shows "The SAC will become unavailable soon. The computer is shutting down."
The server is restart again and again...., and I can't connect to the Azure VM.

What should I do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix it?